# How to move filter/search box from sidebar to top bootstrap

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap 3 and CodeIgniter. In my website I have a list of posts on the left and a sidebar column of the right. In this sidebar I have a search box with input field and a dropdown, another box with a list of 10 popular posts, and another box with a list of categories.

I would like to move only the search box of the sidebar to the top of the site in smaller screen devices. Because it's a search box I would like it to show first and then the posts in mobile view.

I am having trouble doing this. I've managed to reorder the columns, but it's not the result is that the entire column shows first, and I want the search box on top.

Any suggestions?
`pull-left` and `pull-right` did not work for me, or I was unable to make it work. Would using classes with hidden and show values be a better approach?

This is my template for post view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                 
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div id="content" class="content-page">
                <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                <?php echo $content; ?>                                         
            </div> <!-- // content -->
        </div><!-- // col-sm-8 -->

        <div class="col-lg-4">
           <?php $this->load->view('templates/posts_sidebar');?>
        </div><!-- // col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- // row -->
    <hr>
</div><!-- // container -->
```

Sidebar search view is:

```
                    <div class="well post_search">         
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'search', 'role' => 'form', 'autocomplete' => 'off'); ?>
                        <?php echo form_open('posts/filter', $attributes); ?>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4><label for="title"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> <?php echo $text_posts_sidebar_search; ?></label></h4>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title', $this->input->get('title')), 'class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="'.$text_posts_sidebar_search_placeholder.'"'); ?>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <?php echo bt_submit('', '<span class="fa fa-search"></span>', 'btn btn-default'); ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="parent_id"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> <?php echo $text_posts_sidebar_search_in; ?></label>
<?php echo form_dropdown('parent_id', $dropdown_postcategories, $this->input->get('parent_id') ? $this->input->get('parent_id') : '', 'id="parent_id" class="form-control"'); ?>
                        </div>                        
                        <!-- // input-group -->                      
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>                    
                    </div><!-- /well -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I sorted my issue.
Just in case this is helpfull for someone else.

In my template I actually have two search forms now.
One visible and one hidden.

Depending on screen resolution, using media querys I show or hide what I need.